# camera stopped working on rpi2 with buster, device is not detected, hardware has been checked

Tags: pi-2, camera, raspbian-buster

`raspistill -o image.jpg` returns

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

`vcgencmd get_camera` returns `supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0`

On the other hand`v4l2-ctl --list-devices` returns

```
bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
    /dev/video10
    /dev/video11
    /dev/video12
    /dev/video18

bcm2835-isp (platform:bcm2835-isp):
    /dev/video13
    /dev/video14
    /dev/video15
    /dev/video16

Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

I've tried with two cameras, one brand new, and both do not work. I've double checked the hardware connections and that the camera is enable on raspi-config. I don't have another rpi at hand to confirm that the cameras are working. I suspect that the rpi connection might be bust, although except for this problem it is working fine. Any thoughts on ways to debug further? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you still using Buster?

Comment: @CoderMike do I need to update to bullseye? Will it then work?

Comment: I don't know but you are more likely to get support if you are using the latest software. Note the camera utilities changed in Bullseye https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bullseye-camera-system/